# Promote vs Generate

Tags: word-choice

I came across a common mistake in one of the tests I was checking and got stuck on the difference between *generate* and *promote*.

This is the example:

> They are delivering leaflets to every house in order to ___ new business.
>
> A. support
> B. promote
> C. generate

where *generate* is the right answer (at least that's what the answer key suggests).
I wonder if it's a mistake in the key, how do you guys think?

Answer (score 2):

*Generate* is the correct answer. As [Kate](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/90320/kate-bunting) and [Edwin](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/21655/edwin-ashworth) have pointed out, *promote* works with things that already exist, whereas *generate* means making something new.

While leafleting is a form of promotion, "new business" in your example is referring to business that doesn't exist yet.

If you wanted to use *promote* you'd have to talk about a business that did exists. That actually only takes a small change to the sentence:

> They are delivering leaflets to every house in order to promote [a/the/my/etc.] new business.

By adding some sort of determiner the new business becomes existent and so you can use *promote*.